# How to have multiple regex based on or condition in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all `000ANT` and `0BBNTA` from id, is there something similar to [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) which works with regexp or is there any other way? Otherwise I will have to query elasticsearch for each item say 000ANT and 0BBNTA. Please help.

Below is something that I am trying out for 1 i.e., `000ANT` but I also want to have a or condition so regex can also match `0BBNTA`.

```
GET dc/ma/_search
{
   "fields": [
       "host"
    ],
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "regexp": {
                  "_uid": {
                     "value": ".*000ANT.*"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `should` instead of a `must`:

```
{
   "fields": [
       "host"
    ],
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "regexp": {
                  "_uid": {
                     "value": ".*000ANT.*"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "regexp": {
                  "_uid": {
                     "value": ".*0BBNTA.*"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do it with a single regex like `.*(000ANT|0BBNTA).*`, though I'm not sure if it'll perform better or worse than 2 separate.