# ElasticSearch must-terms does not return data

Tags: elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch must-terms does not work, the data has clientId value "08d71bc7-c4ab-6e1d-f858-cf3448242e8b" but the result is empty. I am using elasticsearch:6.7.1. Do you know the problem here?

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "terms": { "clientId": ["08d71bc7-c4ab-6e1d-f858-cf3448242e8b", "08d71bc7-c4ab-6e1d-f858-cf3448242e8c"] } },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*d*",
            "fields": ["name", "description", "title"]
          }
        },
        { "query_string": { "query": "1", "fields": ["type"] } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I share sample data
[image]

Comment: Can you share your mapping and a sample document that should match?

Comment: I added a picture for sample data

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked enough with "query_string"... But if you don't put them and run your query, I'm sure it should at least give you some results. If so, your "query_string"s are the ones that are giving you this bad time

I first recommend you to use "filter" instead of "must".

Consider using the [Regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) your first "query_string". I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30890640/7674214) how to query multiple fields with Regexp.

For the second, it would be enough to use "term" instead of "query_string".

Hope this is helpful! :D

Answer (score 0):

The search results depends on the analysis type of `clientId` . If clientId is a 'keyword' your query should work as expected, but if the type of clientId is 'text' then the value might get tokenized to smaller parts (break at the dash).

You can check the clientId fields type in the index mappings, and also run the analyze API to check the tokenization: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html